# Parse-Server: Unable to query objects

Tags: javascript, parse-server

at the top of my `index.html`, I successfully initialize Parse-Server like this:

```
<script>
    Parse.initialize("MY_KEY");
    Parse.serverURL = 'http://MY_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com/parse/';
    /*var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Test");
    var gameScore = new GameScore();
    gameScore.save({playerName: "Granto"}).then(function(object) {
        alert("SUCCESS BRAHSKI");
    });*/
</script>
```

I know the initialization is successful because I'm able to save a Test Object into the server as shown in the commented code above.

However, When I try and query objects from my server, Nothing happens. What is wrong with my query?

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Test");  
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {
        alert("Query SUCCESS");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Query Error:" + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of the parse library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Syntax for a Parse-Server Query:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Client");

query.find()
  .then(function(results) {
   alert("SUCCESS");
})
  .catch(function(error) {
   alert("ERROR");
});
```